# telethon split Message get number from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am using telethon in python. When I write **.set 14** in Telegram, I want to receive the number 14 and define it as a variable.

```
@client.on(telethon.events.NewMessage(outgoing=True))
async def outgoing(m):
    global ss
    if m.text==".set":
        ss=[int(s) for s in m.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

But when I test it, I get the following error

**AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'split'**

Does anyone have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message means that the `m` variable is a `Message` object and the `Message` object doesn't have a `split` method.  Check out the API for the `Message` object [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/quick-references/objects-reference.html?highlight=message#message).

If you are trying to access the string of the message you need to use the `text` or `raw-text` attributes.

```
ss=[int(s) for s in m.text.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

you will also want to change the `if m.text=='.set':` because right now it only executes the list comprehension if it is exactly '.set' which means there will never be any numbers in the text string.